# Where is the least memory consuming place to put a variable store for get_currentuserinfo()

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Currently, I have a code block that checks to see if the user is logged in. If the user is logged in, it says "Welcome **_**". In the blank spot, there is a variable that reflects an if statement that checks to see if the logged in user has a first name stored in their account, then saves it. If the user doesn't then it, then it saves their user name.

I have the following in my header.php file, but Im wondering if its unnecessary to continually running this script in every page.

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$atriangleUsername = $current_user->user_login;
$atriangleFirst =  $current_user->user_firstname;
$atriangleOutputName = ($atriangleFirst) ? $atriangleFirst : $atriangleUsername;
$urlLogin = site_url('/login/', 'http');
echo '<div id="topSpecialNav" class="text-right row right special-top-right-nav">'; 
echo '<div class="d-inline" style="font-size: 11px;">'; 
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo 'Welcome, '. $atriangleOutputName .'!';
        } else {
            echo '<a href="'. $urlLogin .'">Login</a>';
        }?>
echo '</div>';
```

Where is the best place these blocks, so I am making the least number of calls to my database, but still staying secure?

Comment: I don't understand, what security you are talking about. This code doesn't do any redirects, if the user is not logged in, it just prints a link to login page. For logged in user, it prints: "Welcome".

Answer (score 0):

You should set your user variables (or simply just call them) once you're in your `is_user_logged_in()` block... There shouldn't be any additional strain, and the way you provided is the best way to pull user details from Wordpress.. These properties are set directly from the table columns in the users table and loaded automatically by Wordpress.